# Filtering logic based on three variables

Tags: r

I have a table of data, and I am working on classifying certain results based on three variables. For result to be "Inconclusive", the criteria are as follows:

- For A, B and C, there can only be one result < 37.5
- Of the two variables that are NOT < 37.5, they can either be >= 37.5 or "Undetermined"

Sample table:

| A | B | C | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 39.5 | 33.8 | Undetermined | Inconclusive |
| 38.2 | 35.6 | Undetermined | Inconclusive |
| Undetermined | 38.6 | 38.0 | Inconclusive |
| Undetermined | 36.4 | Undetermined | Inconclusive |
| Undetermined | 35.2 | Undetermined | Inconclusive |

My code will grab results that have one variable < 37.5 where the other two variables are "Undetermined". My code does NOT grab results where one variable is < 37.5, one variable is >= 37.5 and one variable is "Undetermined", but I need it to include those results and I cannot figure out how to tweak my code to do so.
What I have tried:

```
inc <- selected %>% 
  filter((A == 'Undetermined' & 
            B == 'Undetermined' &   
            C < 37.5) | 
         (A == 'Undetermined' & 
            C == 'Undetermined' &   
            B < 37.5) | 
         (B == 'Undetermined' & 
            C == 'Undetermined' &   
            A < 37.5))
```

I have also tried this, and it does not work. This grabs way more results than it's supposed to:

```
inc <- selected %>%
  filter((A == 'Undetermined'|A >= 37.5 &
            B == 'Undetermined'|B >= 37.5 &
            C < 37.5) |
         (A == 'Undetermined'|A >= 37.5 &
            C == 'Undetermined'|C >= 37.5 &
            B < 37.5) |
         (B == 'Undetermined'|B >= 37.5 &
            C == 'Undetermined'|C >= 37.5 &
            A < 37.5))
```

If anyone knows where I am going wrong, please help. The reason I am using the `filter` method specifically is because there is other information in the rows of my table that I need to preserve for a downstream look at what's going on. I can't lose the data from the other columns. Thanks.

Comment: This wouldn't because the columns are not numeric.  It would be either character or factor and thus `>= 37.5` would give incorrect output.  Instead, it should be convert to numeric first i.e. `selected %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric))` and then filter based on the `NA` values and numeric values

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to type of column.  if there is a single non-numeric i.e. character element, it will be `character` class (or could be `factor` as well).  An option is to first convert to `numeric` on those columns and then `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
selected %>% 
    # // convert to numeric - assuming character class and not factor
    # // there will be a warning message while changing the non-numeric to NA
    mutate(across(A:C, as.numeric)) %>% 
    filter((is.na(A) & is.na(B) & C < 37.5)|
          (is.na(A) & is.na(C) & B < 37.5) | 
          (is.na(B) & is.na(C) & A < 37.5)) %>% 
    # // replace the NAs if needed
    mutate(across(A:C, replace_na, "Undetermined"))
```

-output

```
           A    B            C       Result
1 Undetermined 36.4 Undetermined Inconclusive
2 Undetermined 35.2 Undetermined Inconclusive
```

---

Or this could be made more compact (depending on the correct logic)

```
selected %>% 
    filter(if_all(A:C, ~ as.numeric(replace(.,  .== "Undetermined", 
           "36")) < 37.5))
             A    B            C       Result
1 Undetermined 36.4 Undetermined Inconclusive
2 Undetermined 35.2 Undetermined Inconclusive
```

---

Or another option is to select those columns A:C

```
tmp <- subset(selected, select = A:C)
tmp[tmp == "Undetermined"] <- NA
tmp[] <- lapply(tmp, as.numeric)
i1 <-  (rowSums(is.na(tmp)) == ncol(tmp) -1) & 
             (rowSums(tmp < 37.5, na.rm = TRUE) == 1)
i1 
 1     2     3     4     5 
FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE 
subset(selected, i1)
           A    B            C       Result
4 Undetermined 36.4 Undetermined Inconclusive
5 Undetermined 35.2 Undetermined Inconclusive
```

#### data

```
selected <- structure(list(A = c("39.5", "38.2", "Undetermined", "Undetermined", 
"Undetermined"), B = c(33.8, 35.6, 38.6, 36.4, 35.2), C = c("Undetermined", 
"Undetermined", "38.0", "Undetermined", "Undetermined"), 
Result = c("Inconclusive", 
"Inconclusive", "Inconclusive", "Inconclusive", "Inconclusive"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: @jameseking not clear about your expected output.   The code in the first block uses the same logic you showed

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that I needed to change the data type in the columns. I'm still running into the same issue as I point out above however where my code will grab last two rows in my example table above (two columns with NA), but not the first three (one column with NA and one column with a value >= 37.5). And if I use this method `filter((is.na(A) | A >= 37.5 &...)` for all combinations, it grabs way more results than are appropriate, just like I was running into above. The logic is what I'm struggling with as there is one specific condition that slips by. Any other hints?

Comment: @jameseking Please check the updated code with `subset` and `rowSums`.  I read your descrption and tried to make those changes to return the last two rows

Comment: @jameseking your descrption in the post is `My code will grab results that have one variable < 37.5 where the other two variables are "Undetermined".`